# How to clear old values on click of country and state in the form?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a problem in my html form.Now i am in the stage of :  i need to select a country where if i select India i will get a states list of India or again if a change dropdown to Switzerland i will get a text box to type a state. as shown below.

Here in picture i have selected India and state selected as Gujarat.
[image: country with select state]

Here again i have selected Switzerland and state i typed as Bern

[image]

[image]

My Problem is if i change country from Switzerland to Canada. State which i typed as 'bern' remain same, as in third image. so i need to make that field as empty. while i am selecting different country i need to make my state field empty so please help me out [I am using html, js and php ].

SCRIPT :

```
function ShowHideStateDetails()
    {
        if(document.getElementById("ai_country").value == 'India')
        {   
             document.getElementById("ai_other_state").style.display='none';    
             document.getElementById("ai_ind_state").style.display='';
        }
        else
        {  
             document.getElementById("ai_ind_state").style.display='none';
             document.getElementById("ai_other_state").style.display='';  
        }   
    }
```

HTML :

```
       <!-- country -->                       
        <label for="ai_country">Country</label>
        <input id='ai_country' onchange="ShowHideStateDetails()" >

       <!-- State -->    

       <label for="ai_state">State<</label>
       <input type="text" id="ai_other_state">
               <select  id="ai_ind_state" style="display: none;">
                    <option value="">Select</option>                                                    
                    <option value="Andhra Pradesh">Andhra Pradesh</option>                                                          
                    <option value="Arunachal Pradesh">Arunachal Pradesh</option>                                                            
                    <option value="Assam">Assam</option>
                    <option value="Bihar">Bihar</option>
                    <option value="Chandigarh">Chandigarh</option>
                    <option value="Chhattisgarh">Chhattisgarh</option>
                    <option value="Dadra and Nagar Haveli">Dadra and Nagar Haveli</option>
                    <option value="Daman and Diu">Daman and Diu</option>
                    <option value="Delhi">Delhi</option>
                    <option value="Goa">Goa</option>
                    <option value="Gujarat">Gujarat</option>
                    <option value="Uttaranchal">Uttaranchal</option>
                    <option value="West Bengal">West Bengal</option>
               </select>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code shows you how to clear the "state" dropdown and store the value of previously selected state into a hidden variable.

```js
function onIndexChange()
{
 //Store the currently selected value from ai_ind_state to ai__state
 document.getElementById("ai__state").value = document.getElementById("ai_ind_state").value;
 
 //Now clear ai_ind_state dropdown
 document.getElementById("ai_ind_state").value = "";
 
 //Write as output for reference
 document.getElementById("tmp_output").innerHTML = "Last selected state: " + document.getElementById("ai__state").value;
 
}
```

```html
<form>
<select name="country" onChange="onIndexChange()" id="country">
 <option value="">Select Country</option>
 <option value="1">C1</option>
 <option value="2">C2</option>
 <option value="3">C3</option>
</select>
<select name="ai_ind_state" id="ai_ind_state">
 <option value="">Select State</option>
 <option value="1">S1</option>
 <option value="2">S2</option>
 <option value="3">S3</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="ai__state" id="ai__state">
</form>
<span id="tmp_output"></span>
```

Comment: document.getElementById("ai_ind_state").value = "";     so i got solution thank you kutekrish.

Comment: how can i supply that state in value for hidden field.    <input type="text" id="ai__state" value="  ">  i need to supply [ ai_other_state]  values in hidden attribute how can i

Comment: When you handle the onChange event, you can keep track of the values in your hidden input field

Answer (score 1):

you can use jQuery to reset state input when country change:

```
$( "#country-dropdown" ).change(function() {
  //fetch new data for dropdown (ie. by ajax)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Finalize answer for the above question is just to added few lines in script, so its works...!!!

```
<script>
    function ShowHideStateDetails()
    {
        if(document.getElementById("ai_country").value == 'India')
        {   
             document.getElementById("ai_ind_state").value = "";
             document.getElementById("ai_other_state").style.display='none';    
             document.getElementById("ai_ind_state").style.display='';
        }
        else
        {    
             document.getElementById("ai_other_state").value = ""; 
             document.getElementById("ai_ind_state").style.display='none';
             document.getElementById("ai_other_state").style.display=''; 
        }   
    }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [onChange](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) event of the select box to detect changes, and update the state input field if required (emptying the field, and/or change its type).

Answer (score 0):

Simple and quick fix is on change of your country dropdown refresh your state dropdown.